# Basic form action not working on heroku (but works locally)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

EDIT: I feel so stupid, I wasn't merging my branches properly with git.  Like I said, I am quite new to programming and am prone to these types of errors.  I appreciate the help, though.

I am on ch. 7 of the Rails by Example book, where I created a basic "Sign up" form.  When I submit the form on my localhost, it works properly by directing me to either

LOCALHOST/new (back to sign up page, registration info error) or LOCALHOST/show (user profile, success).

When I push this same app to heroku and hit the submit button, it always leads me to this url:

appname.heroku.com/form_action.asp?fname=&email=&password=&password=  which tells me 
"The page you were looking for doesn't exist.  You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved."

Instead of appname.heroku.com/new or /show.

I am so confused, I am a beginner programmer and it boggles my mind why things work so perfectly on the localhost but not on the production server.  Please help!

My code is on github:
https://github.com/Chamza/Sample-App2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the 'cedar' stack on Heroku? I believe the url should be `appname.herokuapp.com` -- not `appname.heroku.com`. Since your code in github is based using rails 3.2.1, you should be using the cedar stack.

Here's some information on the cedar stack from heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar

Also, can you run `heroku logs --tail --app my-app-name` and then post what happens when you click the link? That's known as 'tailing the log' and it will give you real-time output of what's happening.

EDIT***

I looked at your code and I can see that at least one problem is the form you're using has:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<div style = "width: 200px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <form  action="form_action.asp" method="get">
    <h1>Sign up</h1>
    <p align="left">Name:</p>
    <input type="text" name="fname" />  
    <p>Email:</p>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <p>Password:</p> 
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <p>Password Confirmation:</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" /> 
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

There are a few errors in the form. First, the action is to `form_action.asp`. That looks like it came from an old project. Second, the end `</div>` and `</form>` tags are switched -- the form tag should be before the div tag.

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<div style = "width: 200px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <form  action="form_action.asp" method="get">
    <h1>Sign up</h1>
    <p align="left">Name:</p>
    <input type="text" name="fname" />  
    <p>Email:</p>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <p>Password:</p> 
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <p>Password Confirmation:</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" /> 
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

It's likely that your local machine has different code on it than what you have deployed on Heroku. I'd check carefully -- do a `heroku releases --app my-app` and it will tell you what the latest git commit is on the server.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am on cedar stack and it is herokuapp.com not heroku.com.

Comment: I feel so stupid, I wasn't merging my branches properly with git.  So yes, the code I had locally was different from the one on heroku. Like I said, I am quite new to programming and am prone to these types of errors.  I really appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: No problem. You'll get better with time. Keep at it.